# URL Rewrite syntax

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've just been having a look at this, and have gotten halfway to what I would like to do.

So I've got it working by changing my .htaccess file to include:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/LodgeID/(.*)/ index.php?LodgeID=$1
RewriteRule index/LodgeID/(.*) index.php?LodgeID=$1
```

Which is rewriting:

http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/lodgedetails/index.php?LodgeID=288

To:

http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/lodgedetails/index/LodgeID/288/

And I've resolved the issue of my paths to images and CSS files going AWOL.

What I would like to be able to do is include a variant of the lodge name in the URL.

I do have a field in the lodges table which has a short name string which could be used, e.g.:

africanhorsebacksafaris

Is it possible to use rewrite the URL to:

http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/[i]lodgename[/i]/

Where 'lodgename' is stored as a field in the same lodges table as LodgeID?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a way to take the short name string and map it to the correct lodge (or lodge ID) in your index.php, then you can just do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?LodgeName=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So if the request is made for `http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/africanhorsebacksafaris`, it will get rewritten to: `/index.php?LodgeName=africanhorsebacksafaris`.

Comment: I added:

    RewriteRule index/(.*)/ index.php?GSG_URL=$1
    RewriteRule index/(.*) index.php?GSG_URL=$1

to the .htaccess file.

And that gives me:

http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/lodgedetails/index/africanhorseback/

I tried:


    RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?GSG_URL=$1
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?GSG_URL=$1


To get to:

http://lodges.goodsafariguide.com/lodgedetails/africanhorseback/

But it didn't like that, and didn't show any data.

Is there a tweak in the syntax, or does it always need to reference the .php page?

Answer (score 0):

Just to say I have this all working now with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?GSG_URL=$1
```